# JQuery Autocomplete, Parsing JSON results

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Not new to programming, but new to Javascript and JQuery.

Having a difficult time figuring out where to parse the JSON results I receive back from an AJAX query for JQuery's autocomplete.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  function split( val ) { 
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
  } 
  function extractLast( term ) { 
    return split( term ).pop();
  }

  $('#related').bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) { 
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({ 
    source: function( request, response ) { 
      $.getJSON( "/api/v1/indicator/", { specific: extractLast( request.term ) }, response);
    }, search: function() { 
      var term = extractLast ( this.value ) ;
      if ( term.length < 2) { 
        return false;
      }
    }, focus: function() { 
      return false;
    }, select: function( event, ui ) { 
      var terms = split( this.value );
      console.log(terms);
      terms.pop();
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      terms.push( "" ) ;
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

The JSON result looks like this:

```
{"data": [{"value": "dfdsfsdfasdf.com"}]}
```

and I want to populate the '#related' input with the results I get back from the AJAX query.

Edit 1:

Alright, so here's the new section of code:

```
                source: function( request, response ) { 
                    $.getJSON( "/api/v1/indicator/", { specific: extractLast( request.term ) },
                    function(data) {
                        var indicatorItems = [];
                        $.each(data, function(k, v) { 
                            $.each(v, function(i, indicator) { 
                                indicatorItems.push(indicator['value']);
                            });
                        });
                        console.log(indicatorItems);
                        response(indicatorItems);
                    })
```

Now, it's still not showing in the auto complete UI and I'm not throwing any errors. Which of the functions above (search, focus or select) is where the "response" variable is being passed to and manipulated? I am looking at AutoComplete's documentation and I can't seem to get it right.

Edit 2:

Okay, well apparently it IS working, but it's not displaying in the right container. I can see the results being populated outside of the '#related' input (in the background).

Edit 3:

Got it working! Needed to change the CSS a little using

```
.ui-autocomplete { z-index: 1050; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
source: function( request, response ) { 
      $.getJSON( "/api/v1/indicator/", 
                 { specific: extractLast(request.term ) },  
                 function(data){
                      var indicatorItems = [];
                      $.each(data, function(k, v) { 
                          $.each(v, function(i, indicator) { 
                             indicatorItems.push({
                                  value: indicator['value'], 
                                  label: indicator['value']
                             }
                          });
                      });
                      response(indicatorItems);  

                 });
    },
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense! I added that, and I was able to pass the JSON items I was looking for into the response method, but it's still not showing up in the autocomplete. I can confirm that the list is being populated by a quick console.log. See edit.

Comment: try to pass object with label, value fields

Comment: and what happens in html in debugger? ul.ui-autocomplete is added?

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work and yes correct. Here's what I see on that input in the debugger:

`<input id="related" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: yes, but in body is there inserted ul with class ui-autocomplete and whatever li inside?

Comment: No it doesn't look like it.

Comment: May be you do not apply styles? See my example with response http://jsfiddle.net/o4cj7moe/1/